# Is there a way to combine multiple data sources/metrics into one metric?

Tags: azure, metrics, azure-monitoring

When using Azure Metrics, you can add "Resource->Metric Namespace->Metric->Aggregation" onto a graph, and you can have multiple selections be represented on one graph.

Is where a way, to actually combine multiple sources like that into one data set.

Few exact scenarios I would like to have:

- On event grid topics, there's "Failed requests" and "Unmatched requests" metric, I would like both of them be combined into one representation. Essentially saying "Something went wrong".
- I have a matrix of Logic Apps. X times Y logic apps. Instead of having every single one of them be represented by it's own line, I would like to have X lines, where each iteration of X is a combination of all Y metrics.

I don't see a way to achieve anything like this on the portal, but maybe there are some work arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you can take a look at [azure monitor log query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/examples).

It's similar to sql query, and has some features like join / summarize / render (convert query result to chart). You can try to write some queries to meet your requirements.

The detailed info of query language can be find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/tutorial).

You can try get started from azure portal -> azure monitor -> Logs:

[image]